# obtain the difference between current amount and maximum amount

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I am trying to obtain the difference of two amounts. The first is the current amount of transaction a customer currently did. The other is the highest amount the customer has ever done in a period of two months. My script doesn't seem to be working. instead of giving me the maximum amount value the customer has ever done, it gives me the value of the amount at the first date. 
This is the script I wrote in SQl

```
select 
 a.trans_date, 
 a.card_num, 
 max(a.trans_amount) curr_maxAmount, 
 max(b.trans_amount) prev_maxAmount, 
 (a.trans_amount - max(b.trans_amount)) Amt_Diff 
from e_transaction a, 
     e_transaction b 
where a.card_num = b.card_num 
  and a.trans_date between '20161021 00:00'  and '20161021 23:59' 
  and b.trans_date between '20160801 00:00' and '20160831 23:59' 
  and 
group by a.trans_date, a.card_num, a.trans_amount 
having (a.trans_amount - max(b.trans_amount)) > 99999
```

The database is Sybase. Please help review this script and let me know where am wrong.

Comment: Is it complete ? You have an `and` without anything after it

Comment: Do max(b.trans_amount) in a sub-query, join with its result.

Comment: A note, for the date, you could use `convert(date, '2016-10-21')` (not sure if this is faster ...but this is safer, if you have a transaction at 23:59:01, you are ... ;) )

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the date with convert(date, '2016-10-21'). Although I still get same result.

Comment: Perhaps you can try and join `e_transaction a` to `(SELECT max(trans_amount), card_num FROM e_transaction WHERE trans_date between '20160801 00:00' and '20160831 23:59' GROUP BY card_num)  b` on `a.card_num = b.card_num`

Comment: Sorry, just noticed jarlh's answer - that's precisely what I mean

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked.